# Looping over factors/index of a data.frame in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to figure out the best way of looping over all groups of entries within a data.frame or data.table which share the same value of a index/factor and then looping over all such groups within Rcpp. So taking a specific dataset as an example, consider the diamonds dataset associated with the ggplot2 library:

```
   carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1   0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
2   0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
3   0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
4   0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63
5   0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
6   0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48
7   0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336 3.95 3.98 2.47
8   0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337 4.07 4.11 2.53
9   0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337 3.87 3.78 2.49
10  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338 4.00 4.05 2.39
```

I'd like to loop over all entries with the same value of cut and then do an outer loop over all possible values of cut. Is there a way of doing this or do I need to do part of this using plyr or data.tables first?

Comment: Can you please clarify the operation that you are actually trying to do on the data? There is most likely a way to do this without using loops / Rcpp.

Comment: I'd like to run a series of complex calculations in general such as calculating log-likelihoods, not just a simple series of calculations like sums. All the calculations will be performed using the data within each group separately but they require the whole group's data.

Comment: It seems like what you are looking for entails some sort of  `DataFrame` subsetting on the C++ level. Implementing this kind of functionality in a general way (e.g. not specific to only the `diamonds` data set) would require a great deal of effort, almost certainly necessitating extensive C++ templating / generic programming. If you would like to provide the code for your intended operation, I'm sure that someone will be able to suggest a reasonably efficient approach using `data.table` or `dplyr`, both of which contain features specifically for grouped calculations.

Comment: That's what I feared, there's no easy way to do this in the general case. So I guess I should use `data.table` or `plyr` to first group the data and then potentially use `rcpp` to operate on this group using my own routines.